# PHP project, going from local to online

Tags: php, google-app-engine, heroku, zip

I'm currently working on a project which involves:

1. Downloading a zip file from an API (bing ads, to be specific).
2. Unzipping the file (to get a csv), editing it and making database queries.
3. Re-zipping the file and uploading it back to the API using a service similar to the one used to download the zip file in the first place.

I'm restricted by the client libraries of the API to write the project in PHP. I've already written the project to run locally, and hence store the files on my hard disk.

However, I want to have the whole process running on-line. I've tried to use the Google App Engine, but the zip archive class doesn't seem to be working (although it does work locally).

I don't have much experience with putting apps on-line and I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: not sure the zip archive is available on google app engine.

Comment: Get some hosting (free or not). Not much else to say :)